# How do I remove a dmg from a bootable USB flash drive?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I created a bootable flash drive using the instructions on Ubuntu's website using OS X 10.6, but it was for the wrong version of Ubuntu. Now, I want to remove the dmg from the flash drive, but diskutil isn't letting me remove it.

Comment: WHen you say diskutil isn't letting you remove it; what are you trying to do exactly?
PS You managed to make a bootable usb from a mac?! I tried it earlier this week and it didn't work..not even from cd lol

Answer (score 3):

Open the USB drive in Finder and delete the contents that way. Then empty the Trash before ejecting the USB drive.